# Custom function in R with nested for loops for Adress Parsing

Tags: r, parsing, split

Currently working on parsing out address elements such as directionals, street suffix's (rd) or unit type/and unit number. I'm trying to write the following code as a 'function' so that I can just define the list of valid strings (in this example street types are searched for

```
st.list <- c("St","st","stree","Stree","street","Street","dri","Dr",
             "Ave","Rd","Ln","ct","CT","Ct","blvd","blv","bl","Aly",
             "Blvd","Cir","Hls","Ln","Loop","Pl","Way","Vis","Road",
             "Drive","Blv","Blvd","Bl")
```

and then remove this string from the sub-stringed address, store in another vector[iteration],
and repeat this for additional lists of address elements to be parsed into separate columns. The code works but I can't understand why it doesn't work as a function, where I simply define the list to scan for and vector to cut/paste into..

**x is the list of string matches to scan against, y is the character vector to cut and past into
*st is the address character vector.

basically the first 'for loop' runs the code block for each individual address in the vector 'st'.

the nested 'for loop' runs for each substring in the individual address, and checks the list for elements to parse out.

edit - sample address and suffix vectors included

```
    st <- c("101 Gilligans Isle","HWY 66","205 2nd st","530 Williams Stree",
        "301 Weenie Hut Way","400 Grand Ave")

postmast-r package would have already seperated the following street suffix's so that a list of the vector populated from address's above would consist of the following below

    st.suf <- ("","","St","","","Ave")

which would have seperated such suffix elements leaving the remaining address vector looking like this

    st <- c("101 Gilligans Isle","HWY 66","205 2nd","530 Williams Stree",
        "301 Weenie Hut Way","400 Grand")

it is far from being comprehensive in terms of strings it parses, so thus the hard-coding of possible mis-spellings and following loops to seperate the suffix data. As you can see in the real example frequencies below, "Stree" will be seperated from this example where the postmast-r package missed it.
```

```
#scan.replace <- function(x,y){

x <- st.list
y <- st.suf
i <- 1

  for (add in st){
  
    diced <- unlist(strsplit(add, " +"))

    num.w <- length(diced)
  
    j <- 1
  
    for (sub in diced){
      
        if(sub %in% x){
            y[i] <- sub
            diced[j] <-  ""
            j <- j + 1  }
    
        else{j <- j + 1}
    }
  
    diced <- str_trim(diced, side="both")
    i <- i + 1
 }

}
```

```r
I want to be able to call code block for criteria and lists such as below
#scan.replace(st.list, st.suf)

    print(st.suf)
    print(y) #aka what would overwrite st.suf after function
```

New to functions, coming from macros in SAS where the proceedure is a bit different, but I am trying to accomplish a similar thing in that I need to just re-run a block of code many times - just changing two variables each time.

Any ideas?

EDIT: this is what the loop achieves, due to the nature of the data I have limitations on what can be included here.

For the purpose of this demo I'll comment out the 'function' line and manually assign x and y, to demonstrate what i'm able to accomplish but not in reproducible way (as in using a single function call to execute for different elements).

Comment: Hi welcome to SO what is workingstreetsuffixvector?

Comment: Thanks! the street suffix vector is a partial list of street suffix's, which was initially filled by the 'postmastr' package. This didn't completley parse out all suffix's (Road, Rd, St, Street, etc) so this for loop intents to scan for left-over address elements. That's not the name in my code, but rather an explicit name for this example to demonstrate the inputs of the function - being a list of strings to scan for (provided above) and the character vector which remaining address elements will be filled into.

Comment: you need to include it to make a reprex

Comment: Now included are sample vectors for the street address and already semi-populated suffix vector from postmastr

Comment: Also as an update on the project, it made more sense to hard-code the loop function for each address element to be parsed, as there were slight variations in the if-then logic. I am still very curious about creating R functions in general, and how to include multiple processes in a reproducible code block with the ability to define one 'macro variable' at the beginning.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to use the provided function for separating unit names (apt, trailer, space) and directionals (S,N,W,E) I would ideally be able to execute with the additional two lines after the function had been defined #scan.replace(unit.list, st.type)...#scan.replace(directional.list, st.directional)

Comment: I suppose I have been trying to define two 'macro variables' at the begining, is that the problem?

Comment: You should take another look at the `postmastr` package. It already does what you want. See [this vignette section](https://slu-opengis.github.io/postmastr/articles/postmastr.html#street-prefix-and-suffix-data) about parsing street suffix data. In addition, it looks like you can pass a custom dictionary to [pm_streetSuf_parse](https://slu-opengis.github.io/postmastr/reference/pm_streetSuf_parse.html) if you want to match non-standard suffixes like "stree" or "way". I would advise you to read the vignette thoroughly: parsing adresses is hard, don't re-invent the wheel :)